# How to get the value of rotate in the transform attribute of an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

CSS:

```
div { 
   width: 200px; 
   height: 200px; 
   background-color: red; 
   transform: rotate(45deg); 
   margin: auto; 
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var div=document.querySelector("div")
```

How do I get the value of div rotate in the script tag?

Comment: It's not a trivial thing to do, see this very helpful article:  https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/